# Setting the form elements default value in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to figure out whether the user has did any changes on the page. 
Below is what i am doing to achieve this. 
I am accessing the asp.net form elements in the javascript as below

```
var _totalElementsPresent = document.getElementById("aspnetForm").elements.length;
for( var i=0;i<_totalElementsPresent;i++)
  {
var _formObject = document.getElementById("aspnetForm").elements[i];
  switch(_formObject.type)
    { 

case 'select-one' :
        case 'select-multiple':
                    for (var j = 0; j < _formObject.options.length; j++) 
                    {
                    if (_formObject.options[j].selected !=_formObject.options[j].defaultSelected)
                    _flag = 1;        
                    }


  case 'radio' :
                    if (_formObject.checked != _formObject.defaultChecked)
```

I am setting the radio button selected false as below

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="CopyRadioButton" runat="server" Text="Copy"
                                    Checked="false"/>
```

but _formObject.defaultChecked will be set to true.

How to set the radio button checked= false and dropdown selected= true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your if statement: Remember that _formObject.checked will be undefined if the input doesn't have a "checked" attribute. (The absence of the attribute is a valid way of indicating that the input is not checked) Try switching your if statement around:

```
if (_formObject.checked == _formObject.defaultChecked) 
{
    // the value has not changed
}
else
{
    // the value has changed
}
```

**EDIT:**  The same goes for the select attribute on the dropdown options